# Laravel how can use route inside controller?

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I need to get the static Route:: inside controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class processController extends controller
{
    public function process()
    {
       Route::get('myroute', myController@method);
    { 

}
```

I have try to use: use Illuminate\Routing\Route; But this is not working.

Comment: This won't work.  By the time your controllers are hit, the routes have already been registered and this won't be available either for the next request either.

Comment: I don't care if Works, i wan't pass the static Route inside my controller just this. "SIMPLE" just this!

Comment: Okay, all you should need is `\Route::get('myroute', 'myController@method');`  Keep in mind this is like asking how to buy tickets to a sporting event after the event has already finished so anything you try to do with this will just end up wasting your time.

Comment: @user3158900, I've tried tell him it's a nonsense, but he doesn't want to hear that. )

Comment: Yes, ok! But i don't care if that have a sense! I wan't pass the Route::get(); inside from my controller! 
Please guys, let's communicate

Comment: So what do you mean by it not working?  Are you getting an error?  What are you expecting to see happen?

Comment: It's ok this works fine!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will end up calling a controller method.

Rather than Using Route inside Controller call Controller Method directly.
You can also call a controller method from another controller like this:

app('App\Http\Controllers\YourContoller')->methodName();

Comment: Wow this is very interest! This give me the same object with the Route?

Comment: for example can say:  app($myController)->resource($myRequestPage)->methodName($myMethod); I thing not! this can be don only with: Route::resource('myroute', myController@method);

Comment: But i like that! Is very usefull

Comment: Yes this is batter solution, app('App\Http\Controllers\myController')->method();

Comment: If that is solution of your question. You can accept it as answer

Comment: No i do not except this answer, my question is clean. But is usefull for other things

Comment: What you actually wan to do inside your process method?

Comment: Rahman Qaiser doesn't matter what i want to do. My question is how can pass the Route::resource(); inside to my controller

Comment: Ok i thing i have got you.

Comment: What you are trying to do is to process a request where it has to hit.
You Got Route::resource('name','Controller'), And in your process method you want to process it on its actual route. If it is for update it must hit the update route. is that what u want?

Comment: `app('App\Http\Controllers\YourContoller')->methodName();` this is working in get method. But I want to pass request data with method. How can i pass?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send user to the route, you can do this:

```
redirect->route('myroute');
```

If you want to build a path to route, just use this:

```
$url = route('myroute');
```

Comment: I need to get the static Route:: inside controller

Comment: Do you mean you want to **create** new route with controller method?

Comment: I want use exactly the: Route::get('myroute', myController@method); from my controller

Comment: Well, it's really unclear what are you asking. What exactly do you want? Can you describe it please.

Comment: I want use exactly the: Route::get('myroute', myController@method); from my controller! Just this, i am very very clear :) you know how can do that?

Comment: No you're not clear. You said you want `Route::get` several times, but `Route::get` is just defines a route. It's kind of map for web server and app which defines what to do each request. Now, do you want to **create** new route for  future requests, or do you want to make route and **go** to it, or do you want to **get** current root name?

Comment: I want use exactly the: Route::get('myroute', myController@method); inside from my controller and later I will think how to use it, but now I need only this: To pass the Route:: inside to my controller as you can see, i am very clear

Comment: *and later I will think how to use it* -  So, you want to use it, but you don't know why you want it. Cool.

Comment: Yes! exactly! You now how can do that my Professor, hahaha :p

Comment: Ok, I'll answer you like this "you can't define route dynamically". When you'll decide why you want this, we'll help you with your task.

Comment: The decide is my problem! I ask only how can pass the static Route::get(); etc. inside from my controller, i know is possible, but i don't know how! You know how? or not? If not, Because other people maybe can do that

Answer (score 0):

you can use;

```
 return redirect()->action('MyController@methodname');
```

to get redirected to a specific controller method